# Cannot detect leading and trailing spaces oninput

Tags: javascript, string, google-chrome, user-input, sanitization

In Chrome 86, for whatever reason, JS seems incapable of detecting leading and trailing spaces in user input derived from an `input[type=email]` element on the `input` event. I have tested multiple ways of detecting such spaces (e.g. `Str.includes(' ')`, `/\s/.test(str)`, etc) and none of them work.

Does anybody know a workaround?

Comment: Mystified here about your issue... Here is a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/dyXqJbO?editors=1011) where I get `"86.0.4240.111", " test ", true, true`

Comment: It works for me. 
Chrome version is " 86.0.4240.183（Official Build） （64 bit)" on windows.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette youre using the `change` event, not the `input` event

Comment: @hoge do you mind creating a demo on codepen that demonstrates its working, so that i can verify that its something wrong on my end? thanks <33

Comment: I updated the codepen with the input event... But same thing.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette yeah i just played around with your codepen myself and noticed it still works. issue must be on my end. i just realized too that for some reason this function in Visual Studio has a turquoise name instead of a yellow name like all my other functions. [here is a screenshot.](https://i.postimg.cc/25rRB988/snippet.png) i bet this is whats causing it. any idea why this is happening?

Comment: @oldboy Here is my code [CodePen](https://codepen.io/dsnull/pen/ExyeoNP)

Comment: Same function name used for a class somewhere... See [problem reproduced](https://postimg.cc/tsxMndYM)

Comment: I didn't know the turquoise color was indicating name conflicts thought. Thanks to your question ;)

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette i thought it wouldve been indicating a conflict, but if i change the name to gibberish, its still turquoise :(

Comment: @hoge thanks man. i think it may be due to whatever is causing the name of the function in Visual Studio to be turquoise [(pic)](https://i.postimg.cc/25rRB988/snippet.png). any idea what may be causing this? it doesnt seem to be a naming conflict

Comment: @oldboy Is your code using react component?

Comment: @hoge no react in my code

Comment: @hoge myb it is working. i forgot that the one thats not working is actually `type=email`.i edited your codepen and it doesnt seem to work there either

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette myb it is working. i forgot that the one thats not working is actually `type=email`.i edited hoge's codepen to `type=email` and it doesnt seem to work there either

Comment: @oldboy i tried with `type=email` and saw it reproduced. Leading and trailing spaces are trimed by Chrome. [CodePen4email](https://codepen.io/dsnull/pen/MWeqBWQ)
Is this behavier unacceptable to you?

Comment: Ha ok. See [MDN input type email](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/email) and look for the Value paragraph at point #3.

Comment: @hoge i dont notice much of a diff. i think what im going to do is simply prevent space input via keyboard with `keydown`, and then `preventDefault` on `drop` and `paste` for the `type=email`. then ill handle the other too which are `type=text` otherwise. appreciate your help <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input of type `email` is different from the input of type `text`. There is some input automatic validation to ensure the value is properly formatted.

> The input value is automatically validated to ensure that it's either empty or a properly-formatted e-mail address (or list of addresses) before the form can be submitted.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/email)

I assume that is why the spaces gets "removed" from the value your are testing. There are 3 possible value formats:

- Empty string
- One single properly formed email address
- A list of coma-separated email addresses.

The pseudo-classes `:valid` and `:invalid` are autoamtically applied on the input and you can used them for styling and logic.

```js
document.querySelectorAll("input[type='email']:valid").forEach(field=>{
  console.log(field.value + " is valid" )
})

document.querySelectorAll("input[type='email']:invalid").forEach(field=>{
  console.log(field.value + " is invalid" )
})
```

```css
input:valid{
  background: green
}

input:invalid{
  background: red
}
```

```html
<input type="email" value="abcdef"/><br>
<input type="email" value="someone@somesite.com"/><br>
<input type="email" value=""/><br>
<input type="email" value="someone@somesite"/>
```

Notice that an empty field is considered *valid* as well as an email address without TLD...

Comment: i wanted a simple way (i.e. without relying on `keydown` and the endless key values)  to prevent users from inputting unacceptable keys. u know of any way i can clear the spaces from the `type=email` element?

Comment: The leading and trailing spaces are not removed from the input box... But they are removed from the `value` property. That is why you could not detect them. --- I always done it using type text anway.. This "attemp" from the browsers of doing automatic validation is not reliable. The only good reason to use them is about accessibility concerns... Conformity to screen readers things. But you can reach that conformity with a `label` too.

Comment: i got around it by using `keydown` and `drop` to prevent spaces for the email field. anyways, but `type=email` is convenient so that you dont have to validate email addresses yourself, and also gives CSS access to `:valid` and `:invalid` pseudo selectors. is `/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+\/=?^_\`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}
[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/` which is provided on MDN's `type=email` page actually completely effectively equivalent?